# RxJava2 Observable backpressure

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, backpressure

recently I realized that I don't understand how `RxJava2` backpressure works.

I made small test and I expect that it should fail with `MissingBackpressureException` exception:

```
@Test
public void testBackpressureWillFail() {
    Observable.<Integer>create(e -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            System.out.println("Emit: " + i);
            e.onNext(i);
        }
        e.onComplete();
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .doOnNext(i -> {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("Processed:" + i);
    })
    .blockingSubscribe();
}
```

System out shows next:

```
Emit: 0
Emit: 1
Emit: 2
...
Emit: 10000

Processed:0
Processed:1
Processed:2
...
Processed:10000
```

Why it doesn't produce `MissingBackpressureException`.

I expect that `e.onNext(i);` will put item into buffer of `ObservableObserveOn` and after it's size is greater than `static final int BUFFER_SIZE = Math.max(16,Integer.getInteger("rx2.buffer-size",128).intValue());`

It should throw `MissingBackpressureException` which doesn't happen. Does the buffer automatically grow? If not where are items stored?

Comment: `Observable`s in RxJava2 don't support backpressure, only `Flowable`s do

Comment: I know that, they doesn't support backpreassure, but I thought that doesn't support means that  MissingBackpressureException would be thrown, not auto grow of buffer.

Comment: @RostyslavRoshak "Observable doesn't support backpressure" means that when there is a source emitting items faster than the consumer can handle them, these items are buffered unboundedly and it will be the case until an OutOfMemory exception is thrown because of the resources' shortage. However, for a Flowable, as long as the buffer (which is bounded) is full, a MissingBackpressureException is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because backpressure moved out to `Flowable`only with RxJava2, see [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#backpressure).
If you will switch to `Flowable` with `BackpressureStrategy.MISSING` you will get the exception.
That also means that in your case you indeed have buffer that automatically grows, 
  from `observerOn` docs:

> Modifies an ObservableSource to perform its emissions and notifications on a specified Scheduler, asynchronously with an **unbounded buffer**...

Comment: Thank you, Could you please explain, what is the reason of having public final Observable<T> observeOn(Scheduler scheduler, boolean delayError, int bufferSize) in Observable, if buffer is unbounded? Am I correct that it would be the size in which buffer would grow?

Comment: yet, I think that too, according to documentation this is the configurable size of "island" which are the incremental step of the buffer.

Comment: @RostyslavRoshak Indeed, this bufferSize parameter is only for the incremental step of the buffer. The Observable buffer's size is always set to 128 elements by default and it gets incremented as needed.